# laravel angular not passing value to angular function

Tags: angular, laravel

So I have a table that is being loop by angular in my table and I have a separate function to get the status of each data in the loop

```
<tr ng-repeat="history in data.bills">
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;"></td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.referenceno}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.category}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.productCode}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.amount | number : 0}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;" ng-init="checkStatus(history.referenceno)">@{{status}}</td>
    <td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;">@{{history.datecreated}}</td>
</tr>
```

my angular function

```
            $scope.checkStatus = function(transactionID) {
                $http.get('checkstatus/' + transactionID).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.status = data.status;
                });
            };
```

but i'm having trouble with the results. it shows the same not different status.
I am expecting 1 processing and 2 Transaction not found status. but it returns 3 transaction not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all showing the same status because because every loop is binding the result of the function call to the same variable so the result will always be which ever service call resolves last. If you want it to work then you will need to bind each loop to its own variable. One suggestion, bind the result back to the history object:

```
$scope.checkStatus = function(history) {
    $http.get('checkstatus/' + history.referenceno).success(function(data) {
        history.status = data.status;
    });
};
```

And your HTML:

```
<td class="ng-cloak min-w-td" style="text-align:center;" ng-init="checkStatus(history)">@{{history.status}}</td>
```

Comment: oh. wow! just wow. this is what I really need. you saved my day @Simon K Thank you very much.